# Javascript function with php code in yii

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, url, yii

I have multiple javascript functions with ajax calls. At first I put them in view file like this

```
<?php

 Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(
    "test",
    "function test() {
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          data: 'id=120',
          url: '".CController::createUrl('person/getname')."',
            success: function(name){
               alert( name);
        }
          });
      };
  ",
CClientScript::POS_READY
);

...

?>
```

It works, but I have many functions like this, so I'd like to put them in other file than view. I can put it in javascript file,

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/user.js');
```

but than I can't use the `CController::createUrl('person/getname')` to get the url.

What is the best approach to do it?

Comment: JS folder is in "yiiroot/js".

Comment: Sidenote: Not sure where you found this, but `createUrl()` is not a static method. You should always use `$this->createUrl()` or `Yii::app()->createUrl()` instead.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl I've found it in another post, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `CController::createUrl('person/getname')` inside a script file, because its php. If you want to use the url inside script file you must pass it by assigning to a variable.
Use `registerScript()` method to declare the variables from php